# map values based on condition in kdb

Tags: kdb

I have a set of trade data like the following:

| date | sym | asset | points | tenor |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020.11.10 | ABC | FX | 0.2 | "AN" |
| 2020.11.15 | ABB | DX | 0.1 | "AN" |
| 2020.11.17 | AAA | FX | 0.1 | "ON" |
| 2020.11.1 | ABB | FX | 0.3 | "AN" |
| 2020.11.1 | AAA | FX | 0.1 | "SW" |

for the asset=FX the tenor has to mapped/updated with below:

```
"AN"->"AN/3S"

"ON"->"0N"

"SW"->"1W"
```

The result should look like:

| date | sym | asset | point | tenor |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020.11.10 | ABC | FX | 0.2 | "AN/3s" |
| 2020.11.15 | ABB | DX | 0.1 | "AN" |
| 2020.11.17 | AAA | FX | 0.1 | "0N" |
| 2020.11.1 | ABB | FX | 0.3 | "AN/3s" |
| 2020.11.1 | AAA | FX | 0.1 | "1W" |

I have tried the naive approach already. Is there a way to do it programmatically?
For reference the table name is data and it is partitioned on date

Answer (score 1):

Try below query, where `t` is the table:

```
update tenor: (`AN`ON`SW!`$("AN/3S";"0N";"1W"))@/:tenor from t
```

It looks up dictionary `` `AN`ON`SW!`$("AN/3S";"0N";"1W") `` for [each tenor on the right](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/maps/#each-left-and-each-right).

Comment: ```update tenor: (`AN`ON`SW!`$("AN/3S";"0N";"1W"))@/:tenor from t``` in my case tenor is a string and asset is Symbol i.e `FX. i want to update as table rather than dictionary and store the same in data like ```data:update tenor: (`AN`ON`SW!`$("AN/3S";"0N";"1W"))@/:tenor from t```  
par: Unsupported operation on a partitioned table or component thereof kdb I'm getting this the error. FYI: All the tenor values are strings and FX is symbol. data: update tenor^(`$"AN/S3";`0N;`1W) `AN`ON`SW from (select tenor from data where asset = `FX) throws mismatched types error how do i fix this errors.

Answer (score 1):

We can create a set of indices for the tenors we want to update using the find (`?`) operator.
We then use those indices to index into our corresponding map.

Finally we fill forward with `tenor` in case there were any tenors not covered in our mapping (you could replace this with a suitable fill of your choice).

The where clause ensures we only perform this operation on FX assets. As it seems your are working with a date partitioned table I have also added a date clause to further constrain the query

```
q)update ("AN/3S";"0N";"1W") ("AN";"ON";"SW")?tenor from select from data where date within 2020.11.01 2020.11.20,asset = `FX
date       sym asset point tenor
----------------------------------
2020.11.10 ABC FX    0.2   "AN/3S"
2020.11.17 AAA FX    0.1   "0N"
2020.11.01 ABB FX    0.3   "AN/3S"
2020.11.01 AAA FX    0.1   "1W"
```

Comment: par: Unsupported operation on a partitioned table or component thereof kdb I'm getting this the error.
FYI: All the tenor values are strings and FX is symbol.
```data: update tenor^(`$"AN/S3";`0N;`1W) `AN`ON`SW from (select tenor from data where asset = `FX)``` throws  mismatchedtypes error

or somethinglike
```update tenor^("AN/S3";"0N";"1W") "AN""ON""SW" from (select tenor from data where asset = `FX)```
gives error message incompatible lengeh

Comment: You cannot perform an update statement directly on partitioned data, this would explain your par (`partition) error.  You will need to first select the data into memory (which you seem to be doing in your second example) and then apply the update to that data. Word of warning - if you are operating on a large date partitioned database you should also include a date clause in your select (select ... from ... where date within (d1;d2)) this will constrain your query to dates you're actually interested in (and likely speed things up).

Comment: I have updated the answer to reflect the new info